# augmenting data with HTTP service in Mulesoft 4

Tags: mulesoft, mule4

I have a use case where I want to read a JMS message from a queue, take the message contents, which is a JSON document, and augment 2 fields with values returned from an HTTP request and then pass on the original message, with the augmented values, on to the next shape.

So for example:

- from JMS consumer:

```
{
 "f1": "val1",
 "f2": "val2",
 "f3": null,
 "f4": null
}
```

I have a HTTP service that will return:

```
{
 "foo": "fooval",
 "bar": "barval"
}
```

what I want to be available to shapes later in the flow is:

```
{
 "f1": "val1",
 "f2": "val2",
 "f3": "fooval",
 "f4": "barval"
}
```

My flow as of writing this looks like:

JMS consumer -> HTTP Request -> logger

I am not sure how to get the message augmented with those HTTP request values and pass it to the logger. The HTTP Request will set the payload to:

```
{
 "foo": "fooval",
 "bar": "barval"
}
```

How would I retain the payload from the JMS consumer and simply augment the payload with the HTTP request values?

I feel like my approach is not right ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set that the output of any operation [to a variable](https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-runtime/4.3/target-variables) instead of the payload. For example the HTTP Request output can be set to the target variable `foobar`. Then you can use a Transform component to create the output desired in base to the input `payload` and `vars.foobar`. Transform basically let's you write a DataWeave script that does the transformation. You'll need to learn a bit of [DataWeave](https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-runtime/4.3/dataweave) to write the right script.

Having said that, it is not clear what's the logic to get the output. Just updating the value of payload.f3 with the value of vars.foobar.foo and similarly with payload.f4? That should be easy, but it is not clear that's what you want.

Example:

```
<http:request ... target="foobar" targetValue="#[message]">
```

The DataWeave script inside the Transform could be something like this:

```
%dw 2.0
output application/json
---
{
    f1 : payload.f1,
    f2 : payload.f2,
    f3 : vars.foobar.foo,
    f4 : vars.foobar.bar
}
```

Comment: that was soooooo helpful. I am fairly new to Mule and your explanation pointed out a few things I didn't know. Most useful was I didn't realize you could put the HTTP Request to a var. In my case it was overwriting the payload from JMS and that's where I was struggling the most.

Comment: You can also send the JMS Listener output to a var if you want. It works with almost any component that provides an output.